# Opening an attachment via Ajax Call with POST in new window

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This question is similar to how this code works

```
 lukWindow = window.open(url, 'signLukup', 'height=720,width=720,menubar=0,location=0,toolbar=0,status=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1');
```

The goal is to read an attachment and view it on another window while hiding the url as well.

Is it possible to do it with ajax POST instead? I would like to pass the parameter while hiding it in the url so I can't use GET. and my goal is something like this

```
 let obj = {};
 obj.param1 = 1;
 obj.param2 = 2;
 $.ajax({
        url:'main/viewAttachment',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 'data': JSON.stringify(obj) },
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        },
        success: function (data) {
            // open a new window here with content as data
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```

Comment: You would have to pass all of your received data from the success handler, to the popup window now. But a Data URI likely won't work for that - Firefox for example blocks them regarding top-level navigation, for security reasons.

Comment: This would really be much easier, if you submitted a normal form with a `target` attribute, instead of using AJAX. You can either open the popup window before the form submits - or let the browser automatically create a new tab, based on the `target` attribute, when it realizes no window instance under that name currently exists. I personally would give the latter preference, because "popups" with specified dimensions are a bit of an anachronism; for example in _my_ browser settings, I have deactivated that completely - _every_ window.open call will only ever open a new, full-sized tab.